# "No rows were found" on “Automation” SOAP RetrieveRequest

Tags: soap-api, automation, marketing-cloud

I am trying to retrieve automation object by following this guide

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/interacting-with-automation-studio-via-the-web-service-soap-api.html#Retrieve

I received an innerException in results. ErrorMessage: "No rows were found"

```
 // Create RetrieveRequest
            etAPI.RetrieveRequest rr = new etAPI.RetrieveRequest();
            rr.ObjectType = "Automation";

            rr.Properties = new string[] { "ProgramID", "Name", "CustomerKey" };


            etAPI.SimpleFilterPart filter = new etAPI.SimpleFilterPart();
            filter.Property = "CustomerKey";
            filter.SimpleOperator = etAPI.SimpleOperators.equals;
            filter.Value = new string[] { "MY AUTOMATION CUSTOMER KEY" };
            rr.Filter = filter;
```

I also read this post, about using ProgramID, have a simple filter in the request.

[Object Reference Error on "Automation" RetrieveRequest](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62687/object-reference-error-on-automation-retrieverequest)

I've also tried using different filter value:  Status = 1, or IsActive = true, Name = "blah" with no luck, any one has any ideas please?

The API username I am using has permission to access AutomationStudio

[image: Permission setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Automation is not retrievable via SOAP API. I need to change it to "Program" and send raw XML request to endpoint.